# Warum wird Konjunktiv 2 benutzt?

Tags: subjunctive

In folgendem Satz wurde der Konjunktiv II verwendet:

> Die Professorin wirft die Frage auf, ob Anonymität im Internet Vorteile bringen würde.

Ist das richtig oder sollte der Satz besser im Indikativ stehen?

Comment: Klingt gut genug für mich.

Answer (score 5):

Ich möchte die Frage einmal von der semantisch-pragmatischen Seite angehen, nicht von der morphologisch-syntaktischen. Oder kurz: Fragen wir einmal nach Bedeutung und Verwendung, nicht nach Grammatikregeln.

In freier Wildbahn können vier Varianten dieses Satzes vorkommen:

> Die Professorin wirft die Frage auf, ob Anonymität im Internet Vorteile bringt.

Der von dir vorgeschlagene Indikativ. In dieser Form würde man den Satz vor allem in mündlicher Kommunikation antreffen. (Oder auch: In dieser Form trifft man den Satz vor allem in mündlicher Kommunikation an.)

> Die Professorin wirft die Frage auf, ob Anonymität im Internet Vorteile bringen würde.

Das ist für mich die "Normalform" dieses Satzes in einigermaßen elaborierten schriftlichen Texten. Es ist, wie BestGuess schon anmerkte, eine indirekte Rede plus irrealem Bedingungssatz ("Anonymität, **wenn** es sie denn gäbe! - Es gibt sie aber nicht.")

Achtung jedoch: Will der Sprecher keine irreale Bedingung ausdrücken, sondern bloße indirekte Rede, so kann er "bringen würde" hier nicht verwenden! In reiner indirekter Rede würde man sagen:

> Die Professorin wirft die Frage auf, ob Anonymität im Internet Vorteile bringe.

Dies drückt indirekte Rede aus, sagt aber nichts zur unterstellten Realität/Irrealität des Szenarios aus. Man erfährt also nicht, ob die Professorin Anonymität im Internet als real existierend oder als nur hypothetisch angenommen darstellt. - Diese Form scheint mir inzwischen fast ein bisschen altertümlich oder jedenfalls selten geworden zu sein. ("Er fragte ihn, ob man das heute noch so verwende.")

Nun gibt es noch die Variante:

> Die Professorin wirft die Frage auf, ob Anonymität im Internet Vorteile brächte.

Für mein Empfinden ist dies gleichwertig mit dem "bringen würde"-Satz (schließt also den Gedanken "Es gibt solche Anonymität aber nicht" ein), ist aber ein bisschen gehobener (oder gestelzter?) formuliert. Aber hier ließe ich  mich gerne auch belehren, wenn jemand dazu tiefere Einsichten hätte.

Comment: Warum kann man *bringen würde* nicht als bloße indirekte Rede verwenden? Nur, weil sich dann eine unangenehme Mehrdeutigkeit ergibt (ergeben würde, ergebe)?

Answer (score 2):

Korrektur der ursprünglichen Antwort:

Die Wahl des Konjunktivs ist etwas kompliziert, da es sich sowohl um indirekte Rede als auch einen "irrealen Bedingungssatz" handelt.

Der Bedingungssatz (analog zum Beispiel in der Definition) ist "Wenn es Anonymität im Internet gäbe, würde dies Vorteile bringen?".

> Verwendung des Konjunktivs II
>
> 2. Irreale Bedingungssätze
>
> Der Bedingungssatz wird meist mit der Konjunktion wenn eingeleitet.
>
> Wenn ich ein Vogel wäre, wäre ich ein Falke.
>
> Der Bedingungssatz drückt eine hypothetische Annahme aus. Die Bedingungen und die Folgen sind nicht real gegeben. [1](https://www.deutsche-grammatik.net/grammatik/zeiten/konjunktiv-i-und-ii/)